# iptables linux code causing internet issues

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall

I was looking for a way to block all internet input/output on my linux with the exception of a few chosen applications, and I found the following script which uses the iptables command:

> before the script is run, a group called 'internet' is created (`sudo
>   groupadd internet`).

```
 #!/bin/sh
 # Firewall apps - only allow apps run from "internet" group to run

 # clear previous rules
 sudo iptables -F

 # accept packets for internet group
 sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --gid-owner internet -j ACCEPT

 # also allow local connections
 sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
 sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 192.168.0.1/24 -j ACCEPT

 # reject packets for other users
 sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REJECT

 # open a shell with internet access
 sudo -g internet -s
```

*source:* https://plus.google.com/+TobyKurien/posts/YZhZJCZmGgm

The only problem is that it doesn't seem to work for me. After running the script, I use the same terminal to call firefox by just typing `firefox`, the browser opens, but there is no internet access. All I get is **Server not found**. Before having run the script, the internet access was fine.

**QUESTION:** Why might I be getting this issue? I understand the code being executed, and I can't figure out exactly why the firefox browser wasn't able to get a connection.

Comment: You only have TCP protocol rules listed... or are you forcing DNS to do TCP only?

Comment: I did plan on adding `udp` as well @ivanivan, however since not even the `tcp` was working by itself, I decided to debug the code as is intead of adding more lines. It's strange cause the **source** link's author seems to have gotten it to work.

Comment: How do you know TCP is working? The error you posted, "Server not found", is indicative of a DNS issue, which is UDP. If you were having a TCP issue, you should get something along the lines of "connection timed out" or "connection refused".

Answer (score 1):

Generally, what one finds in the standard Centos/RHEL 6 release is which basically allows outgoing traffic but restricts incoming traffic to SSH is:

In `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

```
 # Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
 # Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
 *filter
 :INPUT DROP [0:0]
 :FORWARD DROP [0:0]
 :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
 -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
 -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
 COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

## First, clean all rules that maybe is running on the system

```
iptables -X
iptables -F
iptables -Z
```

## Then, established the default policy

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

## Allow everything local

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

## Then start to open services [ports]

For example, surf the network.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Follow the same scheme rules for another rule.

If you see any mistake, English is not my main language.